# Wrong with function 'plot', maybe

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate Nodal clustering coefficient distribution with a connectivity matrix
But when I operate this code, it return nothing. What is the problem? 
Can't I use function plot like that?

```
cm = [0,1,1,1,0;1,0,0,1,0;0,1,0,0,0;1,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0];
bg = biograph(cm);

for i = 1:5
    intNodes = getrelatives(bg.nodes(i));
    num = numel(intNodes);
    plot(i,num);
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to plot will erase the previously plotted data, unless you write

`hold on`

before the loop (or unless you edit the axes properties).

```
cm = [0,1,1,1,0;1,0,0,1,0;0,1,0,0,0;1,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0];
bg = biograph(cm);
figure %# create new figure
hold on %# create axes, make sure that plots get added instead of replaced
for i = 1:5
    intNodes = getrelatives(bg.nodes(i));
    num = numel(intNodes);
    plot(i,num);
end
```

Comment: See also `hold all`,  hich automatically changes line color for each graph

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably going to run better if you first gather all the data points, and only plot them in the end. Here is how this can be done:

```
cm = [0,1,1,1,0;1,0,0,1,0;0,1,0,0,0;1,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0];
bg = biograph(cm);

plotData = NaN(5,1)
for i = 1:5
    intNodes = getrelatives(bg.nodes(i));
    num = numel(intNodes);
    plotData(i)=num
end

plot(1:5,plotData)
```